# Windows Mobile Device Center (6.1) not starting?

Tags: windows-7, windows-mobile, debug

I am trying to start windows mobile device center on windows 7 machine. But it only shows me the small green window that is shown at loading time:

[image]

It is then closed automatically. I am not getting what the problem is.

I tried to uninstall the previous update then re-installed again but the problem is not gone.

Comment: Never mind the update: did you try removing the full application from the Windows features, rebooting, and then adding it again?

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult to tell exactly what the issue is without more information, can you check the event log to see if there are any error messages in it?
Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Log/Event Viewer

Error messages should come from either WcesComm or RapiMgr.

Answer (score -2):

Try to change the service account from "Local service" to "Local system".
I solved the same problem like that on windows 10.